# Getting Nested Objects Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
const object = {
  user1: {
    "article1": {}
  },
  user2: {
    "article2": {},
    "article3": {},
    "article4": {}
  },
  user3: {
    "article5": {}
  },
  user4: {
    "article6": {}
  }
};
```

I can count the user articles using method below.

```
const user1count = (object && object.user1 && Object.keys(object.user1).length) || 0
const user2count = (object && object.user2 && Object.keys(object.user2).length) || 0
const user3count = (object && object.user3 && Object.keys(object.user3).length) || 0
const user4count = (object && object.user4 && Object.keys(object.user4).length) || 0
```

Is there a more optimal method someone can suggest? I would prefer an object like one below.

```
const counts = {
  user1: 1,
  user2: 3,
  user3: 1,
  user4: 1
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to get the desired output:

```js
const object = {
  user1: {
    "article1": {}
  },
  user2: {
    "article2": {},
    "article3": {},
    "article4": {}
  },
  user3: {
    "article5": {}
  },
  user4: {
    "article6": {}
  }
};

const counts = Object.entries(object)
                     .reduce((r, [k, o]) => (r[k] = Object.keys(o).length, r), {});
                     
console.log(counts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check like this `object && object.user1`. Just loop on outer object keys and then find the length. Create final object using reduce.

```js
const input = {
  user1: {
    "article1": {}
  },
  user2: {
    "article2": {},
    "article3": {},
    "article4": {}
  },
  user3: {
    "article5": {}
  },
  user4: {
    "article6": {}
  }
};

const output = Object.keys(input).reduce((prev, key) => {
   prev[key] = Object.keys(input[key]).length;
   return prev;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `map` the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object. Create an array of entries with the same key and the value set the length of keys. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the entries to an object

```js
const object = {
  user1: {
    "article1": {}
  },
  user2: {
    "article2": {},
    "article3": {},
    "article4": {}
  },
  user3: {
    "article5": {}
  },
  user4: {
    "article6": {}
  }
};

const entries = Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.keys(v).length]),
      output =  Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use forEach loop

```html
const object = {
  user1: {
    "article1": {}
  },
  user2: {
    "article2": {},
    "article3": {},
    "article4": {}
  },
  user3: {
    "article5": {}
  },
  user4: {
    "article6": {}
  }
};


Object.keys(object).forEach(o => {
  console.log(o, Object.keys(object[o]))
  if (typeof object[o] == 'object') {
    console.log(Object.keys(object[o]).length);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const counts = Object.entries(object)
    .reduce((acc, entry) => ({
        ...acc,
        [entry[0]]: Object.keys(entry[1] || {}).length
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). First, you can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the entires to objects (with the key being the user and value the number of keys in that user object) and then assign each individual object in the mapped array to a single object:

```js
const object = {user1: { "article1": {} }, user2: { "article2": {}, "article3": {}, "article4": {} }, user3: { "article5": {} }, user4: { "article6": {} }};

const res = Object.assign(
  {}, 
  ...Object.entries(object).map(([key, obj]) => ({[key]: Object.keys(obj).length}))
);

console.log(res);
```